# preg_replace usage in php

Tags: php, preg-replace

can someone tell me if there is posibility to use one pattern for multiple replacement?I have a pattern, and a replacement array and I seek to replace the matches sequentially from the array. Like
match = > array[0]
match = > array[1]
and so on. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go with a `preg_replace` with callback:

```
preg_replace_callback('/pattern/', function () {
    static $replacements = array('foo', 'bar', 'baz');
    return array_shift($replacements);
}, $subject);
```

Each subsequent match will get the next entry from the replacement array.

Comment: one more moment, how not to make static array in the callback function but pass it via parameter? when I pass my array like `preg_replace_callback($pattern,function($arr){ .... },$subject);` I get the same values as were before.??

Comment: You'd use the closure aspect to do that: `..., function () use ($arr) { ... }, ...`.

Comment: thanks, that means I can use something like
`...,function() use ($arr){ return array_shift($arr);},....` ?